# sftp with chroot and file creation problem

Tags: linux, sftp

I configured second sshd systemd service using own sshd configuration with different tcp port configured in it and following configuration of sftp subsystem:

```
Match Group sftponly
  ChrootDirectory /srv/%u
  AllowTcpForwarding no
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
  PubkeyAuthentication yes
  PasswordAuthentication no
  PermitTunnel no
  AllowAgentForwarding no
  X11Forwarding no
```

The user I created in sftponly group is:

```
uid=1001(sftpuser) gid=1001(sftponly) groups=1001(sftponly)
```

The directory tree for chroot is:

```
drwxr-xr-x   3  root     root           22 Aug 27 15:43 /srv
drwxr-xr-x   4  root     root           34 Aug 27 18:27 /srv/sftpuser
drwx------   2  sftpuser sftponly       29 Aug 27 15:43 /srv/sftpuser/.ssh
-rw-r--r--   1  sftpuser sftponly      398 Aug 27 15:43 /srv/sftpuser/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

I can successfully do sftp with the private key however I can't create any file in user's /srv/%u chroot directory:

```
sftp> ls -al
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root           18 Aug 27 16:38 .
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root           18 Aug 27 16:38 ..
drwx------    2 sftpuser sftponly       29 Aug 27 13:43 .ssh
sftp> mkdir one
Couldn't create directory: Permission denied
sftp>
```

When I do ***chown sftpuser /srv/sftpuser*** and go back to active sftp session I can create files but when I logout I can't login sftp anymore, until I change back `/srv/%u` directory to be owned by root

```
Connection to 192.168.1.110 closed by remote host.
Connection closed
```

I can of course create additional directory inside `/srv/%u` (/srv/sftpuser) owned by sftpuser but is this the only solution with chroot? Why user can't change/upload files directly to `/srv/%u`?

Additional question - how to prevent other users on the system from using this custom sshd configured for sftp only? When I set above `Subsystem` line in the custom `sshd_config_sftponly` two options: `PubkeyAuthentication` and `PasswordAuthentication` to **no** and do restart sshd daemon, regular system users can still login with their password using that custom sshd port.

Comment: Try using the first configuration under "The directory tree for chroot is:" and create a directory "/srv/sftpuser/writeable" owned by "sftpuser" with group write permission for "sftponly".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can of course create additional directory inside /srv/%u (/srv/sftpuser) owned by sftpuser but is this the only solution with chroot?

```
# man sshd_config | col -b | sed -n '/^ *ChrootDirectory/,/^ *$/{/^ *$/q;p}' | \
fmt -w72 | sed 's/^/    /'
     ChrootDirectory
         Specifies the pathname of a directory to chroot(2)
         to after authentication.  At session startup sshd(8)
         checks that all components of the pathname are root-owned
         directories which are not writable by any other user
         or group.  After the chroot, sshd(8) changes the working
         directory to the user's home directory.  Arguments to
         ChrootDirectory accept the tokens described in the
         TOKENS section.
```

Let's be explicit - *all components of the pathname are root-owned*! Thus you just can do:

```
# man sftp-server | col -b | sed -n '/^ *\-d/,/^ *$/{/^ *$/q;p}' | \
fmt -w72 | sed 's/^/    /'
     -d start_directory
         specifies an alternate starting directory for users.
         The pathname may contain the following tokens that
         are expanded at runtime: %% is replaced by a literal
         '%', %d is replaced by the home directory of the user
         being authenticated, and %u is replaced by the username
         of that user.  The default is to use the user's home
         directory.  This option is useful in conjunction with
         the sshd_config(5) ChrootDirectory option.
```